# How to exit while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I don't understand why I cannot go out from simple loop.

Here is the code:

```
a = 1

#tip checking loop
while a != 0:
    # tip value question - not defined as integer to be able to get empty value
    b = input("Give me the tip quantinty which you gave to Johnnemy 'hundred' Collins :")
    # loop checking if value has been given
    if b:
        #if b is given - checking how much it is
        if int(b) >= 100:
            print("\nJohnny says : SUPER!")
        elif int(b) < 100:
            print("\nJohnny says : Next time I spit in your soup")
    elif b == '0':
        a = 0

    else:
        print("You need to tell how much you tipped")

print("\n\nZERO ? this is the end of this conversation")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```py
a = 1

#tip checking loop
while a != 0:
    # tip value question - not defined as integer to be able to get empty value
    b = input("Give me the tip quantinty which you gave to Johnnemy 'hundred' Collins :")
    # loop checking if value has been given
    if b:
        #if b is given - checking how much it is
        if int(b) >= 100:
            print("\nJohnny says : SUPER!")
        elif int(b) < 100:
            print("\nJohnny says : Next time I spit in your soup")
        if b == '0':
            a = 0

    else:
        print("You need to tell how much you tipped")

print("\n\nZERO ? this is the end of this conversation")
```

the following condition

```
if b == '0':
    a = 0
```

should be in the same scope as the `if b:` condition.

Comment: Yes, I solved it right now. Also the statement  that if b<100 need to have additional requirement that b !='0'. Without that it is ending verification to early. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can`t break out of the loop because. actually, there is no`break`. You need to put`break` command at the end of every loop branch where you would like to stop looping in order to break out of the loop.

Also, you could break out assigning `a = 0` instead of the `break`.